# Why do I get this error while editing the .profile file while installing cakephp on mac?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mamp

I'm installing cakephp on mac osx lion on MAMP. And I get the following error when I save the .profile file with the corresponding path.

```
-bash: export: `=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.4.10/bin:/Users/aravind/Sites/cake/lib/Cake/Console:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin': not a valid identifier
```

My .profile currently only consists of the following lines. I have no idea what this error means and why it refers to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework...

```
alias www="cd /Users/aravind/Sites/public_html"
alias mysql="cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -p"
export PATH ="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.4.10/bin:/Users/aravind/Sites/cake/lib/Cake/Console:$PATH"
```

Due to this, I'm not really able to continue with the installation of cakePHP. Help with this please?

Comment: There is a space between `PATH` and `=`. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: It worked. Thanks heaps! As a beginner, I'm a little curious as to how a small space like that can cause an error regarding files/folders that aren't even in consideration, here being the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework...

Comment: The reason is that if you have a space, then `export` does not interpret your argument as a name=value pair, but as two separate names. I.e., it tries to export `PATH` and `=/Applications/...`, but the second of these is not a valid name for `export`'s purposes (because of the initial `=` character), so it complains.